# Commit same changes for all the branches?

Tags: git, github, push, branch, commit

Maybe this is a general question but I have not found any clear answer.
I was wondering whether it is possible to perform a change in some file that is available for several branches and push/commit this change throughtout all or several of the branches, not only the current one.
I am thinking that this might be useful when you are programming in a protocol but the changes you are making (for example an improvement) can be applied to all the other protocols of the same general project.

Cheers